# Fullscreen, full dpi WebGL canvas on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, mobile, webgl, webvr

There are any way to make size of canvas on mobile device 1 to 1 to devices screen real pixel size?

This is important for google cardboard (VR) application support directly from site. (in this case dpi really matters)

Currently the only way using viewport target-densitydpi is deprecated and not working on modern browsers.

Comment: make a application with webview widget?

Comment: I need it on my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use CSS to decide what size you want the canvas. Then look up what size the browser is displaying the canvas in CSS pixels using `canvas.clientWidth` and `canvas.clientHeight`. Now multiply that by `window.devicePixelRatio` to get the number of device pixels those CSS pixels represent and set the canvas's content/drawingbuffer size to match.

Example:

1. Make a canvas

   ```
   <canvas id="c"></canvas>
   ```
2. Set its size using CSS

   Here I'm making the canvas be the size of the viewport (the window).

   ```
   html, body {
     margin: 0;     /* remove the default margin */
     height: 100%;  /* make the body fill the window */
   }
   canvas {
     width: 100%;    /* make the canvas fill the body */
     height: 100%; 
     display: block; /* make the canvas not cause a scrollbar */
   }
   ```
3. Look up the size it's displayed and match its drawingbuffer size.

   ```
    function resizeToMatchDisplaySize(canvas) {
      var displayWidth  = canvas.clientWidth  * window.devicePixelRatio;
      var displayHeight = canvas.clientHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
      if (canvas.width !== displayWidth || canvas.height !== displayHeight) {
        canvas.width  = displayWidth;
        canvas.height = displayHeight;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
   ```
4. Before rendering each frame adjust the size

   ```
    function render() {
      // resize before rendering in case of resizing or rotation
      if (resizeToMatchDisplaySize(gl.canvas)) {
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight); 
      }


      // render scene

      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
   ```

Here's an example drawing some lines

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("#c").getContext("webgl", { alpha: false });
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ['vs', 'fs']);
var ids = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  ids.push(i);
}
var arrays = {
  vertexId: { size:1, data: ids},
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

var uniforms = {
  time: 0,
  numIds: ids.length,
  resolution: [0, 0],
};

function resizeToMatchDisplaySize(canvas) {
  var displayWidth  = canvas.clientWidth  * window.devicePixelRatio;
  var displayHeight = canvas.clientHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
  if (canvas.width !== displayWidth || canvas.height !== displayHeight) {
    canvas.width  = displayWidth;
    canvas.height = displayHeight;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function render(time) {
  // resize before rendering in case of resizing or rotation
  if (resizeToMatchDisplaySize(gl.canvas)) {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  }
  
  // render scene
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  uniforms.time = time * 0.001;
  uniforms.resolution[0] = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
  uniforms.resolution[1] = gl.drawingBufferHeight;
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.LINES, bufferInfo);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
  <script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute float vertexId;

varying vec4 v_color;

uniform float numIds;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;

#define PI radians(180.0)

vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c) {
  c = vec3(c.x, clamp(c.yz, 0.0, 1.0));
  vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
  vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
  return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}


void main() {
  vec4 offsets = vec4(
    sin(time), 
    sin(time * .13) * PI * 2.,
    sin(time * .43) * .5 + 1.,
    cos(time * .17) * .5 + .5);

  vec4 centers = vec4(
    sin(time * .163) * .5,
    cos(time * .267) * .5,
    sin(time * .367) * .5,
    cos(time * .497) * .5);

  vec4 mult = vec4(
    1.,
    (sin(time * .1) * .5 + .5) * 3.,
    0.,
    0.);

  vec2 position = vec2(vertexId / numIds, mod(vertexId, 2.));
  vec2 offset = mix(offsets.xz, offsets.yw, position.y);
  float a = mult.x * position.x * PI * 2.0 + offset.x;//mix(u_offsets.x, u_offsets.y, a_position.y);
  float c = cos(a * mult.y);
  vec2 xy = vec2(
    cos(a),
    sin(a)) * c * offset.y +
    mix(centers.xy, centers.zw, position.y);
  vec2 aspect = vec2(resolution.y / resolution.x, 1);
  gl_Position = vec4(xy * aspect, 0, 1);
  
  float hue = position.x;
  float sat = 1.;
  float val = 1.;
  v_color = vec4(hsv2rgb(vec3(hue, sat, val)), 1);
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you've asked 2 questions. How to get native 1x1 pixels and how to go fullscreen. Fullscreen is harder. iOS Safari has no support for the [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API). Chrome for android does but it requires your website be served from HTTPS.

You should also put this in your `<head>` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

And set `user-scalable` to `yes` or `no` depending on what you want

Comment: In your example - browser will do resizing of image from canvas before showing it on screen?

Comment: The browser will set the canvas's display size. The code will then match the canvas's content, it's drawingbuffer, to match the size it's displayed

Comment: Okay, but canvas.style.width and canvas.style.height will remain small?

So how browser will act? Will it resize content inside canvas after drawing?

In any case i can make canvas.width = 10*realWidth - and it looks like browser will do resizing to meet canvas.style.width, or there are some different logic?

Comment: I set the canvas to 100% width and 100% height so it will fill the container. The container is the body which is also set to 100% so the canvas in this case will stretch to the entire screen. I then look up what size the browser made it and make the content match.

The browser will display the canvas whatever size you ask it. I'm asking it to be 100%. If you want to ask it to be something else 10px by 10px the browser will do that too. The code will still do the right thing and make the content 1x1 pixels inside the displayed area since it's looking up the size the browser displayed it.

Comment: Looks like it works, do not know are there any overhead because of different sizes of canvas in dom and for rendering.

Comment: The example above they are the same size. That seemed like the entire point of your question. The size of the canvas (its content) matches the size it's displayed. That's what the code above does.

Comment: @gman your code snippet doesn't work as expected on Redmi 4X, Android 7, Chrome: https://ibb.co/1KmvmTK

Comment: @gman it is an issue of Redmi 4X because your example works on Infinix Hot 30, Android 13 without the problem above

Comment: @gman the same result as on my screenshot above

Comment: @gman it looks like `gl.viewport` uses the default canvas size: 300x150 and it ignores new values

Comment: @gman I created the issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/27723

Comment: @gman It is very interesting that the old Three.js example (from 2018) works without the problem: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/27723#issuecomment-1937044539

Comment: @gman I don't know why but when I set `antialias` to `false` it works without the problem for pure WebGL, Three.js, and Babylon.js

Comment: This is my topic about resizing on old devices in WebGL with solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873424/resizing-webgl-canvas-on-old-android-devices The solution is to disable `antialias` like this: `const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", { antialias: false });`