# Resizing WebGL canvas on old Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, webgl

The next code snippet works as expected on Android 13. It resizes WebGL canvas in Chrome Android browser without problems: https://plnkr.co/edit/H3Swhi3WweVmwgxa

[image]

But on Android 7 (Redmi 4X) it draws only the default size of canvas (300x150):

[image]

Is it possible to solve it? I set a view port like this:

```js
            window.onresize = () => {
                const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
                gl.canvas.width = Math.round(gl.canvas.clientWidth * dpr);
                gl.canvas.height = Math.round(gl.canvas.clientHeight * dpr);
                gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
                draw();
            };
```

Cross-refs:

- https://community.khronos.org/t/resizing-webgl-canvas-on-old-android-devices/110474
- https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/resizing-webgl-canvas-on-old-android-devices/439288

Comment: I have the same problem with Three.js: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/27723 and Babylon.js: https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/the-viewport-dont-scale-on-old-device-redmi-4x-android-7-chrome/47952

Comment: But it is very interesting that I found an old example (from 2018) in Three.js that works in the full screen mode on Redmi 4X without the problem above. Details are here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/27723#issuecomment-1937044539

Comment: I don't know why but when I set `antialias` to `false` it works without the problem for pure WebGL, Three.js, and Babylon.js

Comment: Temporary solution for me is `const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", { antialias: false });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but when I set antialias to false it works without the problem for pure WebGL, Three.js, and Babylon.js. My solution - do not use `antialias`:

WebGL:

```js
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", { antialias: false });
```

Three.js

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
```

Babylon.js:

```js
const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, false);
```

- Three.js topic: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/27723
- Babylon.js topic: https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/the-viewport-doesnt-scale-on-old-device-redmi-4x-android-7-chrome/47952